# .htaccess different directory mapping

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to map the following address

```
http://www.mydomain.com/foo1/
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/dev/foo2/
```

such that anyone who access `http://www.mydomain.com/foo1/` will see contents from `http://www.mydomain.com/dev/foo2/` . Please note that I'm not looking at redirecting.

The following code is in my .htaccess located in `/foo1/` directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dev/foo2/$1 [L]
```

But the result is far from what I want. It maps to `http://www.mydomain.com/dev/foo2/foo1/`
when I try accessing `http://www.mydomain.com/foo1/`

Comment: I left out this point, `http://www.mydomain.com/dev/foo2/` is actually powered by CodeIgniter and have the `index.php` removed from the URL through .htaccess configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^foo1/(.*) /dev/foo2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it still maps to `http://www.mydomain.com/dev/foo2/foo1/`. I actually left out some information. Please refer to my reply in my question. Thx.

Comment: Ah! Crucial bit of info - I use Expression Engine (written on Code Igniter). Try this:
`RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^foo1/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /dev/foo2/%1 [L]`